# Direction on Google design pattern

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, firebase

I need to build a app which has the following design pattern.

- Results displayed on iOS device.
- User data stored online (more than
  just username/password, also data they themselves put in).
- User can sign in with TW/FB etc.
- Computation logic code running on backend, which will need to gather data from online sources, and produce results. The server code will be Node.js or Python.

I think some combination of Firebase and Google App engine will work, but I'm not exactly sure which of the design patterns in the following link is the one I'm looking for.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#design-pattern

?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think the second one will work best.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-standard

You will likely need to use firebase queue to do what you're planning to do.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-firebase-queue_97.html

- Results displayed on iOS device.

  - Using iOS firebase calls
- User data stored online (more than
  just username/password, also data they themselves put in).

  - Using iOS fireabse calls
- User can
  sign in with TW/FB etc.

  - Using firebase authentication
- Computation logic code running on backend,
  which will need to gather data from online sources, and produce
  results. The server code will be Node.js or Python.

  - Using firebase queue running on google app engine

Comment: Thanks for the info. The only issue I can see with Firebase-queue is that I think you have to use Node, which might be the way to go, but I suspect it would be better to have the server logic running in Python.

Comment: That could be. Is there a reason you think it would be better to use Python? Node can certainly handle logic, but you could be absolutely right, there just isn't quite enough information here for me to give you another suggestion. Good luck!

Comment: The server code will be doing sentiment analysis (although Googles prediction API looks interesting), and other ML related things, which Python seems to have sewn up. I know you can do similar things with Node, but for those reasons maybe Python will be a better way to go, unless using Node in this setup is just a lot easier to get going.